# GSAP target undefined not found

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, gsap

With useSate I toggle between two paragraphs of text from french to english. It works fine but I want to set up a nicer transition with GSAP.

My configuration doesn't work because the gsap target is null or undefined.
Can you help me to debug that problem?

The paragraph component with the two buttons :

```
      import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import gsap from 'gsap';

const LanguageDesc = (props) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        isActive: false,
        languageName: 'English'
    });

    let english = useRef(null);
    let french = useRef(null);

    const handleLanguage = () => {
        if (state.isActive === false) {
            setState({
                isActive: true,
                languageName: 'French'
            })
            gsap.from(english.current, {
                duration: 5,
                opacity: 0,
            })
        } else if (state.isActive === true) {
            setState({
                isActive: false,
                languageName: 'English'
            })
            gsap.from(french.current, {
                duration: 1,
                opacity: 0,
            });
        } else if (state.isActive === false) {
            setState({
                isActive: !state.isActive,
                languageName: 'French'
            })
            gsap.from(english.current, {
                duration: 5,
                opacity: 0,
            })
        }
    };


    return (
        <div>
            {state.isActive ?
                <p ref={english} className="eng-text">{props.state.desc_en}</p>
                : null}
            {state.isActive ?
                null
                : <p ref={french} className="fr-text">{props.state.desc_fr}</p>}
            <button className="btn-language" onClick={handleLanguage} > {state.languageName} text</button>
        </div >
    )

};
export default withRouter(LanguageDesc);
```

[image: console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `ref={el => (english = el)}` and the same usage for the `french` ref.

Refs returned by `useRef` are references to a single object that is held in memory across the lifetime of the component. You must read from and write to the ref using the `current` property.

Assigning `english` to the value of `el` does not change the value of the english ref, it *replaces* the ref with `el`. You then access the `current` property on the element, which (since it is not a ref) will always be `undefined`.

`english` is already a ref, so you don't need to handle the assignment yourself. Just do `ref={english}` and React will handle the rest.

#### Update

The issue remains because your code still uses the refs as elements when they are `null`.

When `isActive` is false, there is no `english` element. When true, no `french` element. Yet each event handler depends on both elements being present.

Removing the elements entirely increases the complexity of animating the in/out transitions. Maybe instead you can use `isActive` to determine whether to display each `p` element (`display: none;`), but always render both.

```js
() => {
  const handleLanguage = () => {
    if (isActive) {
      gsap
        .from(french.current, {
          duration: 1,
          opacity: 0,
        })
        .eventCallback('onComplete', () => {
          setState({
            isActive: false,
            languageName: 'English',
          });
        });
    } else {
      gsap
        .from(english.current, {
          duration: 5,
          opacity: 0,
        })
        .eventCallback('onComplete', () => {
          setState({
            isActive: true,
            languageName: 'French',
          });
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p
        ref={english}
        style={{ display: isActive ? 'none' : 'initial' }}
        className="eng-text"
      >
        {desc_en}
      </p>
      <p
        ref={french}
        style={{ display: isActive ? 'initial' : 'none' }}
        className="fr-text"
      >
        {desc_fr}
      </p>
      <button className="btn-language" onClick={handleLanguage}>
        {' '}
        {state.languageName} text
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ooh thank you very much! But it doesn't work anyway

Comment: {current: null}
current: p.eng-text
__proto__: Object

Comment: Can you describe more, or update the question with the new problem?

Comment: I changed the ref to ref={english}, but the result in the end stays the same. I update the code here with ref={english}

Comment: Sorry I missed your update.  I see what you mean, but I'm not sure how you want to proceed to achieve that way :/

Comment: I added some code to show one way it might be able to work.

Comment: Good job!! It's really interesting. The only thing is it's a fade out on the displayed <p>, then the second <p> appears. It's should be the opposite I think for a smoother change

Comment: In that case you may want to add one more piece of state `isAnimating`, and use that in combination with `isActive` to determine whether the `p` elements should be displayed.